# Como usar o RecycleView do Kivy na linguagem KV e com o ScreenManager?

Tags: python-kivy

Estou usando Kivy, para um app.

Tenho um banco de dados no Firebase da Google funcionando bem, consigo salvar lá tranquilamente. Gostaria de retornar esses dados para o meu app, mas antes de ter problemas com isso, não consigo listar nada no Kivy.

Queria usar o ListView do Kivy, mas na documentação ele já diz para usar o RecycleView, mas eu achei ela um tanto quanto confusa (a documentação). Me gerou dúvidas e não consegui usar.

Na documentação do [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView) há o seguinte:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Mas eu uso o [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screen%20manager) para controlar minhas telas, logo, na classe TestApp eu retorno um 'sm', como no exemplo dá própria documentação:

```
# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Se vocês observarem as sintaxes são diferentes, e aí que eu me perco, sem saber o que fazer e como escrever para que os dois trabalhem em conjunto e eu possa gerar uma lista de itens em uma das minhas telas do ScreenManager.

Não consegui encontrar na doc algo que me ajude, mas fiz os códigos testes dessas duas páginas e eles funcionaram, porém não soube como fazer tudo junto.

Tentei o seguinte (No que imagino, era para isso listar 20 itens como Label).
No meu documento onde controlo as telas (ele funciona para todas as outras):

```
class ListaEvento(Screen, RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListaEvento, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]
```

No meu documento kv, que funciona bem para a parte visual das outras telas também:

```
<ListaEvento>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'design/fundo.png'
            size: self.width, self.height    


    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Mas não tive resultado nenhum, ele apenas exibe a tela azul, que é essa que eu puxo no canvas, mas não lista nada. Já cheguei a colocar um print também para testar, mas não aparece no terminal, logo nada está acontecendo. Esse teste de exibir 20 itens é baseado no da documentação, no qual são 100 itens.

A partir disso, pretendo listar itens vindos do meu banco de dados, mas um problema de cada vez. Estou a uns dois dias tentando, desculpem se for algo muito bobo, mas na documentação do Kivy eu não consegui encontrar a resposta.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para fechar a questão e deixar como ajuda caso alguém precise, vou colocar aqui a solução que consegui postando a [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267177/how-can-i-use-the-recycleview-of-kivy-on-kv-language-with-screenmanager) em inglês.

O bom feitor me sugeriu adicionar o RecycleView como um widget filho da minha Screen. Então o código, onde eu tinha minhas telas, ficou dessa forma:

```
class ListaEventos(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListaEventos, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # assigning data in RecyclerView
        self.rv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
```

E no documento kv:

```
<ListaEventos>:
    rv: rv # expose the widget

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'design/fundo.png'
            size: self.width, self.height

    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'Label'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

Isso foi interessante para o meu projeto, pois pude continuar a administração das telas normalmente.